# Display 2 input fields within ng-container and div side by side in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap, ng-container

I'm trying to display 2 input fields and a button side by side. Tried many combinations, but still no luck. The code block of the  and  is below. Can you please help on how to make them on the same row ide by side. Thanks so much

Code:

```
<div [id]="id" class="row" style="margin: 0rem; align-items: center">
...
   <ng-container [formGroup]="igf">
   ...
     <div class="p-0">
     ...
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
        ...
           <ng-container>
           ...
              <input> --first
              <div class="input-group">
              ...
                <input> --second

              </div>
           </ng-container>
        </div>
     </div>
   </ng-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1: No nested `input-group`

**app.component.html**

```
<div [id]="id" class="row" style="margin: 0rem; align-items: center;">
  <div class="p-0">
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm d-flex">
      <input />
      <input />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-leaf-51zn5y?file=/src/app/app.component.html).

#### Option 2: Nested `input-group`

If you want to have a nested `input-group`, then the following code will do the trick. Add `style="display: inline-flex;"` to the second `input-group`.

The code below also works within `<ng-container>`. See [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-cdn-2r6uzb?file=/src/app/app.component.html).

**app.component.html**

```
<div [id]="id" class="row" style="margin: 0rem; align-items: center;">
  <div class="p-0">
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
      <input />
      <div class="input-group" style="display: inline-flex;">
        <input />
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-frost-ezhruo?file=/src/app/app.component.html).

Comment: Cervus, thank you so much for the answer and sorry for the late response. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Also when I inspect some of the div elements. I see flex showing at the end of those elements. But I don't see that in your demo? Could that be a reason? I remember adding them sometime back, but removed it now

Comment: Can you please create a [CodeSandbox snippet](https://codesandbox.io/) (click "Try for free")? **I need to be able to reproduce the problem.**

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by removing a div for the 2nd input and adding class "p-0" to a parent div. But i will still mark yours as correct